Why does getElementValueOfCssProperty return a digit and not the correct value in Selenium?
I'm trying to get get a background color of a element and see if its bold using getElementValueOfCssProperty. For the color it returns "rgba(255, 222, 173, 1)", which I can convert to hex, which aligns what I see in Chrome. But why would it not just return the hex code?
My code in R:
element$getElementValueOfCssProperty("background-color")


When I try to check if a element is bold it returns the value 700. How should I interpret that and why does it, not just return bold
My code:
element$getElementValueOfCssProperty("font-weight")


Website I'm trying on is Wikipedia Olympics

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

The value returned from the getElementValueOfCssProperty are usually the most precise forms. The RGBA format is a standardized way to represent colors in CSS, which includes the alpha channel. Hexadecimal notation does not always shows or supports the alpha channel.
When checking if an element's font is bold, the value returned is 700. This is because font weight in CSS is specified using numeric values:

Normal: 400
Bold: 700

So 700 corresponds to the bold weight.
If you really want "bold" you can convert the returned value like so:
if (font_weight >= 700) {
  fontWeight= "bold"
}

